# React Native - How to manage the native back button with Drawer Navigation

Tags: android, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I recreated the Drawer Navigation following this code: https://github.com/mariodev12/react-native-menu-drawer-navigator

Everything works correctly but now I do not know how to handle the native button to go back .. I would like to always return to the previous page, but if you press twice in the home exit the app.

This is my Code:

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import DrawerStack from './src/stacks/drawerStack';

const Navigator = StackNavigator({
    drawerStack: {screen: DrawerStack}
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'drawerStack'
})

export default Navigator
```

> drawerStack.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {StackNavigator, DrawerActions} from "react-navigation";
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Home from "../components/home";
import DrawerScreen from "./drawerScreen";

const DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator({
    DrawerStack: {screen: DrawerScreen}
}, {
    headerMode: 'float',
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,45,85)',
            paddingLeft: 10,
            paddingRight: 10
        },
        title: 'Home',
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerLeft: <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    if (navigation.state.isDrawerOpen === false) {
                        navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
                    } else {
                        navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
                    }
                }}>
                <Text>Menu</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    })
})

export default DrawerNavigation;
```

> drawerScreen.js

```
import {DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import Home from '../components/home';
import Login from '../components/login';
import Contacts from '../components/contacts';
import News from '../components/news';

const DrawerScreen = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Home},
    Login: {screen: Login},
    Contacts: {screen: Contacts},
    News: {screen: News}
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
})

export default DrawerScreen;
```

> news.js "Example of one page"

```
import React from "react";
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class News extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                <Text> Here Leave the News!! </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, how do I insert the back button in the header instead of the classic menu (DrawerStack) for only the 'News.js' page?

Comment: You need to back button with drawer or you need to remove back button?

Comment: @JAINESHDOSHI I would like to: 1) manage the back button in the drawer on certain pages. 2) manage the native back button of android because currently if the user touches the native back button it immediately exits the app

Comment: @JAINESHDOSHI sorry, I made confusion with the initial question. check this news correct question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757818/react-native-how-to-manage-headers-per-page-with-stacknavigator-and-drawernavi

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this? I am also trying to implement a drawer navigation where back button leads back to the previous page and not directly to the home page.

Answer (score 2):

In Android you have to handle back button actions by yourself with BackHandler from react-native.

First of all

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
```

in ComponentDidMount add an event listener to listen for backpress:

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
}
```

in ComponentwillUnmount make sure you remove the listener:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
}
```

then

```
 onBackPress = () => {

     //inside here do what you want with single back button
 }
```

Checkout this link too:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html

If you want to go back to previous Screen with back button drawer navigation isn't for you and you should try to use Stack Navigator.

Comment: sorry, I made confusion with the initial question. check this news correct question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757818/react-native-how-to-manage-headers-per-page-with-stacknavigator-and-drawernavi

Answer (score 1):

You need create the button in your news screen too, like this.

```
import React from "react";
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class News extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
        return {
            headerLeft: --- PUT HERE YOU CUSTOM BUTTON (Use navigation.goBack() in onPress)
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                <Text> Here Leave the News!! </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

To make better, you can create a new screen with only your custom navigation options.

Comment: i can try to insert:
`static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        headerLeft: <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.goBack()
                }}>
                <Text>Back</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>`
but it had no effect, it seems that the drawerStack is at a higher level, possible?

Comment: Sorry, I forget the "return".

Comment: I tried again with the return, but the problem, reading on the web, is like being able to "chaining" DrawNavigator and StackNavigator to use the menu headers.

at the moment DrawerStack commands on all and on every page, the writing Menu always comes out with the key to open and close the menu on the left.

I continue to investigate ... we hope for a solution :-D

Comment: sorry, I made confusion with the initial question.
I close this question and I reopen a correct one

Comment: check this news question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757818/react-native-how-to-manage-headers-per-page-with-stacknavigator-and-drawernavi