# React Native - how to manage headers per page with StackNavigator and DrawerNavigator

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

This is my actual Code:

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import DrawerStack from './src/stacks/drawerStack';

const Navigator = StackNavigator({
    drawerStack: {screen: DrawerStack}
}, {
    headerMode: 'screen',
    initialRouteName: 'drawerStack'
})

export default Navigator
```

> drawerStack.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {StackNavigator, DrawerActions} from "react-navigation";
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Home from "../components/home";
import DrawerScreen from "./drawerScreen";

const DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator({
    DrawerStack: {screen: DrawerScreen}
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    // navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    //    headerStyle: {
    //        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,45,85)',
    //        paddingLeft: 10,
    //        paddingRight: 10
    //    },
    //    title: 'Home',
    //    headerTintColor: 'white',
    //    headerLeft: <View>
    //        <TouchableOpacity
    //            onPress={() => {
    //                if (navigation.state.isDrawerOpen === false) {
    //                    navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
    //                } else {
    //                    navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
    //                }
    //            }}>
    //            <Text>Menu</Text>
    //        </TouchableOpacity>
    //    </View>
    // })
})

export default DrawerNavigation;
```

> drawerScreen.js

```
import {DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import Home from '../components/home';
import Login from '../components/login';
import Contacts from '../components/contacts';
import News from '../components/news';

const DrawerScreen = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Home},
    Login: {screen: Login},
    Contacts: {screen: Contacts},
    News: {screen: News}
}, {
    headerMode: 'screen',
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
})

export default DrawerScreen;
```

> news.js "example of a page where I want to manage a custom header"

```
import React from "react";
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class News extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'News Header',
    headerLeft: (
        <Button
            onPress={() => alert('This is an example button like hamburgher!')}
            title="="
        />
    )
};
    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                <Text> Here Leave the News!! </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

recapitulating the structure of the Navigator is this:

1) (app.js) -> StackNavigator

2) (DrawerStack.js) -> StackNavigator

3) (DrawerScreen.js) -> DrawerNavigator

what I can not understand is how to declare correctly

> headerMode: 'screen'

in the various Navigator to show on certain pages (example News.js) a specific custom header.

Answer (score 1):

Change header style using `navigationOptions` as below. You can change as your requirement. For more `navigationOptions` see [Configuring the header bar](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html) of React Navigation.

```
 import {DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
 import Home from '../components/home';
 import Login from '../components/login';
 import Contacts from '../components/contacts';
 import News from '../components/news';

 const DrawerScreen = DrawerNavigator({
               Home: {screen: Home},
               Login: {screen: Login},
               Contacts: {screen: Contacts},
               News: {
                       screen: News,
                       navigationOptions: {
                         title: "News",
                         headerTitleStyle: {
                              color: "white"
                             },
                         headerStyle: {
                              backgroundColor: "red"
                              },
                         headerBackTitle: null,
                         headerTintColor: "white"
                         }
                     }
             },{
               headerMode: 'screen',
               initialRouteName: 'Home'
            })

 export default DrawerScreen;
```

Comment: I tried but it does not change anything mmm... the problem think is that the createStackNavigator, present in App.js, seems to be "above everything" and even if specific of the headers directly in the pages, or in drawerScreen.js, are not taken into account...there is a way to do it all again having a drawernavigator and can then arrange the header for individual pages?